# Scala generic type "transmition"

Tags: scala, generics

With a generic definition like this

```
case class Event(a : Int)

trait EventHelper[B <: Event] {
   def getEvent : B
}
def genericFunction[T <: EventHelper[_]](x : T) = {
  x.getEvent.a
}
```

Why B in genericFunction is considerated as Any ? shouldn't be considerated as Event?

My work around is

```
def genericFunction[T <: EventHelper[B], B <: Event ](x : T) = {
  x.getEvent.a
}
```

But it's look to me redundant, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say `T <: EventHelper[_]`, you are using an existential type, which requires special care defining upper and lower bounds:

```
def genericFunction[T <: EventHelper[_ <: Event]](x : T) = x.getEvent.a
```

From the [SLS](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#existential-types):

> Scala supports a placeholder syntax for existential types. A wildcard type is of the form `_ >: L <: U`. Both bound clauses may be omitted. If a lower bound clause `>: L` is missing, `>: scala.Nothing` is assumed. **If an upper bound clause `<: U` is missing, `<: scala.Any` is assumed**. A wildcard type is a shorthand for an existentially quantified type variable, where the existential quantification is implicit.

This means that even though the type parameter of `EventHelper` has an upper-bound of `Event`, `_` will still be inferred by the compiler as `Any` if no upper-bound is supplied for it.